# Loop and convert object string value to object if value has comma

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object:

`{x: '1', y: '1,2,3'}`

I want to loop through it and convert the string to an object if it includes a comma.

The expected result should be:

`{x: 1, y: {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}}`

I have tried using `Object.entries` and `map` as . below but I get an undefined result for everything.

```
Object.entries(oResult).map(el => {
  if(el[1].includes(',')) {
    const aEl = el[1].split(',');
    el[1] = Object.assign({}, aEl);
  }
})
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried please.

Comment: I've updated the question with what I've tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
let obj = {x: '1', y: '1,2,3'},
    strToObj = str => str.split(',').reduce((r,c,i) => (r[i] = c, r), {})

let result = Object.entries(obj)
  .reduce((r,[k,v]) => (r[k] = v.includes(',') ? strToObj(v) : v, r), {})

console.log(result)
```

The idea is to use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to convert a string to an object via first splitting it on the `,` (this is what `strToObj` function does). Then using the [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) you just get the key/value and compose your final object.

You can also make it as a function like this:

```js
let strToObj = str => str.split(',').reduce((r,c,i) => (r[i] = c, r), {})

let convertObject = obj => Object.entries(obj).reduce((r,[k,v]) => 
    (r[k] = v.length < 2 ? v : strToObj(v), r), {})
 
console.log(convertObject({x: '1', y: '1,2,3'}))
console.log(convertObject({x: 'A,BC,D', y: 'D,DD,DDD'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

```js
const data = {x: '1', y: '1,2,3', z: '4,5,6'};

function transform( object ) {
  let index = 0;

  for ( const key in object ) {
    if ( object[ key ].includes( "," ) ) {
      const splitValues = object[ key ].split( "," ) // get object values into array

      object[ key ] = {}; // create an empty object to add the key/value pairs to
      for ( const value of splitValues ) {
        object[ key ][ index ] = value;
        index++
      }

      index = 0; // reset index for next iteration
    }
  }

  return object;
}

console.log( transform( data ) );
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why you've chosen to hide the code snippet. I've never seen this before. Why is it better?

Comment: It's a bit of a habit, since this snippet isn't that large I guess I can unhide it. I usually do it to make the post more readable, especially when there are multiple answers it can be annoying to have large snippets in the way.

Comment: Agreed. In a bigger answer with more context, it might be appropriate, but it just looked a bit strange here.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const yourObject = {x: '1234,1235,1236', y: '1,2,3'};
const res = {};

for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(yourObject)) {
  let split = val.split(',').map(s => parseInt(s));
  split.length > 1 ? res[key] = { ...split
  } : res[key] = split[0];
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Hi this works great but it returns `NAN` if the value is greater than 1 character eg: `x: '1234,1235,1236'

Comment: Thanks I'll test it again.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.fromEntries` to transform objects easily -

```js
const transform = (o = {}) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(([k,v]) =>
    [ k
    , v.includes(',')
        ? Object.fromEntries(v.split(',').map((x, i) => [ i, x ]))
        : v
    ]
  ))

console.log(transform({ x: '1', y: '1,2,3' }))
// { x: 1, y: { 0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3' } }

console.log(transform({ a: 'apple,pear,cherry', b: 'foo,bar' }))
// { a: { 0: 'apple', 1: 'pear', 2: 'cherry' }, b: { 0: 'foo', 1: 'bar' } }
```

Comment: I like this method, I'll test it soon.